# Bottom-right align (using Flex-box) in React-Native not working

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, react-native

Making a to-do list type thing to add in my app but when trying to align the 'add todo' button to the bottom right, the button goes anywhere but there.

I'm pretty good with CSS but get pretty messed up when using React CSS/styles. I've played around with different properties, giving a parent  a style instead of the child etc.

The class is as follows

```
class AgendaScreen extends React.Component {
  addReminder = () => {
    //blank so far :)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>Agenda</Text>

        <View style={styles.reminderView}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.reminderTouch}>
            <Text style={styles.reminderBtn}>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and the styles here

```
  //Agenda screen styles

  reminderView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },

  reminderTouch: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    borderRadius: 100,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },

  reminderBtn: {
    fontSize: 50,
    margin: 10,

    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
  },
```

The goal is to align the plus symbol in the middle of the circle and align that circle to the bottom right. With the pasted settings the circle is in the top left and the plus symbol is aligned to the bottom of the circle.

Also, the code posted above wasn't the closest I've gotten as I could easily do it with padding but I'd prefer to use flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your style replace with this style and Please add style to your top view

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text>Agends</Text>
        <View style={styles.reminderView}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.reminderTouch}>
            <Text style={styles.reminderBtn}>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>




reminderView: {
    flex: 1,
    right:0,
    margin:5,
    bottom:0,
    position:'absolute'
  },

  reminderTouch: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    borderRadius: 100,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    margin: 20,
  },

  reminderBtn: {
    fontSize: 50,
    margin: 5,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }
```

Please check this snack.expo link

Comment: I update my answer please check you need to add style to your top <view> and add bottom:0 to reminderView style       https://imgur.com/a/e8lJDTg

Comment: Sweet, it works. The only problem is if you look close enough, the plus symbol is not vertically centered (low down)

Comment: Yeah i got it if we remove margin it will be in center :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
width:'100%',
paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
padding: 8,
  }}>
    <View
    style={{
      justifyContent:'center',
      alignItems:"center",
      width:65,
      borderRadius:100,
      height:65,
      position:'absolute',
      bottom:15,
      right:15,
      backgroundColor:"red",
      elevation:10
    }}
    >
    <Icon
    name="plus"
    size={25}
    color="white"
    />
    </View>
  </View>
```

What it does is that it makes the round button float on the `bottom right corner` of the screen. Since you are making a todo app, you would want it to float over the todo list when it becomes longer. 
https://snack.expo.io/@ammarahmed/rebellious-donuts